# Prevent my script from using so much memory?

Tags: php, session, memory, crash

I have a script which lists all possible permutations in an array, which, admittedly, might be used instead of a wordlist. If I get this to work, it'll be impossible to not get a hit eventually unless there is a limit on attempts.

Anyway, the script obviously takes a HUGE amount of memory, something which will set any server on fire. What I need help with is finding a way to spread out the memory usage, something like somehow resetting the script and continuing where it left off by going to another file or something, possibly by using Sessions. I have no clue.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?php 
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');

$possible = "abcdefghi";

$input = "$possible";

function string_getpermutations($prefix, $characters, &$permutations)
{
    if (count($characters) == 1)
        $permutations[] = $prefix . array_pop($characters);
    else
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($characters); $i++)
        {
            $tmp = $characters;
            unset($tmp[$i]);

            string_getpermutations($prefix . $characters[$i], array_values($tmp), $permutations);
        }
    }
}
$characters = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++)
    $characters[] = $input[$i];
$permutations = array();

print_r($characters);
string_getpermutations("", $characters, $permutations);

print_r($permutations);

?>
```

Any ideas? :3

Answer (score 0):

You could store the permutations in files every XXX permutations, then reopen files when needed in the correct order to display/use your permutations. (Files or whatever you want, as long as you can free PhP memory)

I see that you're just echoing the permutations, but maybe you'd want to do something else with it ? So it depends somehow.

Also, try to unset as many unused variables as soon as possible while doing your permutations.

Edit : **Sometimes**, using references as you did for your permutations array can result to a bigger use of memory. Just in case you didn't try, check which is better, with or without

Comment: I think I'll have no choice but to do that. How would I go about unsetting the variables?

Comment: Before doing so, use the PhP `memory_get_usage` function to see how is the memory going, when does it starts to grow etc. Then try to split the permutations in files and check what changed on the memory usage. If you see an improvement, then just try to unset any variable when she becomes unused (Or at least arrays, or part of array, as these are the ones taking most memory) and recheck the memory, etc etc until you can't do more.